# jquery ui buttons: how can I add a clicked state look to a button that's not a checkbox or radio button?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a jquery ui button that gets instantiated on a `div` element. I want to achieve the look that a button gets when it's a check box and it's checked. How can I do this is my situation. I've tried:

```
$('#my-div-button').attr('checked', true);
$('#my-div-button').button('refresh');
```

To no avail. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually replicate the behaviour fairly easily.

The DIV toggle button:

```
<div class="ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-widget">button</div>
```

JavaScript to toggle the classes on clicks and hovers, as well as to disable selection:

```
$('div.ui-state-default').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-active');
}).hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-hover');
}).disableSelection();
```

CSS to style the button:

```
div.ui-state-default {
    padding: 0.4em 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/zGvht/3/

Comment: This is clean and answers the OP.  Recommend mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$('#button').addClass('ui-state-active');`

Comment: This works, but the state switches back when the button is hovered over. Do you know of a quick way disable that? Thanks for the help.